# Google App Makerでスクリプト言語を使わずにスプレッドシートの参照、書込は可能でしょうか

Tags: google-apps-script

Google App Makerを利用して、複数のスプレッドシートの情報をテーブルで参照し、更新、削除、追加などをスクリプト言語を使わずに実現することは可能でしょうか。
DBもCloud SQLを利用せず、DB用にスプレッドシートに保存できるようにしたいと考えてます。
ノンプログラマーの私でも、App Makerを利用して、管理アプリを作れないか検討しているのですが、現在ネットで調べながらでは必ずスクリプト言語を利用している感じがあります。

＜やりたい事＞
例えば、従業員の勤怠シート（日時、時間、作業内容）をApp Makerで読み込み、全従業員の稼働時間をAppのページに出力する。　または、勤怠状況を入力する画面をappで作り、そのデータをスプレッドシートへ保存する、、などを作りたいと考えております。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/spyth/items/3ab4c3dc44cd6936a7a0

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/154259